# Can my neighbour see my http traffic?

Tags: security, monitoring, wireshark

My neighbour and I are both using the same internet provider but each has its own account, landline and router.
If my neighbour monitors traffic using wireshark, would they be able to capture my traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Short answer: Yes, and this is [how](http://www.stringcat.com/company_blog/2012/09/09/monitoring-wifi-traffic-of-your-neighbors/)
- Long answer: this is not a Community for this...

Comment: The short answer only applies to WiFi and then when you WiFi router is running WEP (Wired Equivalent Privacy) security which is no longer common but one should check to insure you are using WPA2 (Wi-Fi Protected Access 2) security.

Comment: zaph thanks for the comment, @jipr311 can you update your answer?